# Webpack dynamic require with loaders in require statement

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to use dynamic `require` and `require.context` with explicit loaders in the require statement? I'd like to be able to do something like this, but it's not working for me:

```
var req = require.context('../somedir', false, /\.js$/);
var imported = req('my-loader!' + someModulePath); // someModulePath defined above somewhere
```

When I try this, I get a 'module not found' error that makes it seem like webpack is treating the `my-loader!` part of the string as the start of a file path, but I want `my-loader!` to be recognized as a loader, as described here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#loaders-in-require

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Loaders are run only once at compile-time, which means after your `require.context` is compiled, it's just pure Javascript. You can write it like this:

```
var req = require.context("my-loader!../somedir", false, /\.js$/);
var imported = req(someModulePath);
```

The function returned by `require.context` is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I needed to add an extra exclamation mark before the loader - `!my-loader!../somedir`