# "Unexpected token" error in babel-loader with inline loaders and require.context

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, babel-loader, monorepo

In a basic CRA-app this works just fine:

```
import MyMDX from '!babel-loader!mdx-loader!./mdx-file.mdx';
```

But when I try to do the same with `require.context`, like so:

```
const mdxContext = require.context('!babel-loader!mdx-loader!../../../../packages', true, /(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(mdx?)/);
```

I'm getting a whole bunch of "unexpected token" errors in `babel-loader`:

```sh
../packages/<file-path>.mdx (../node_modules/babel-loader/lib!../node_modules/mdx-loader!../packages/<file-path>.mdx)
SyntaxError: <file-path>.mdx: Unexpected token (11:9)

   9 | const makeShortcode = name => function MDXDefaultShortcode(props) {
  10 |   console.warn("Component " + name + " was not imported, exported, or provided by MDXProvider as global scope")
> 11 |   return <div {...props}/>
     |          ^
  12 | };
  13 |
  14 | const layoutProps = {
```

Anyone know why, or how to get this to work properly?

### Update

I suspect the issue is related to this: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/198

But I do have a `.babelrc` file containing:

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-react-app"]
}
```

And - as I've mentioned - regular ES6 imports works just fine. So it may seem like using `babel-loader` inline somehow ignores `.babelrc`? Making `babel-loader` miss out on the react preset, and thus jsx support?

### Update 2

Now I'm convinced this is related to this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos, and that `babel-loader` ignores `.babelrc` not because I'm using it inline, but because it's used trying to import modules outside of the Create React App root/src folder.

So now the question becomes; [how do I configure a Create React App to use a `babel.config.js` on monorepo root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052180/how-to-configure-create-react-app-in-monorepo-to-use-root-babel-config-js) through Craco (which I'm already using for Less support)?

I've found [this semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323916/how-to-config-webpack-to-transpile-files-from-other-lerna-packages-ejected-from), but the answer requires every sibling package to be specified directly. Is there a way to combine that with `require.context` and dynamically include every sibling package?

Comment: Are you sure you can use inline loaders with `require.context`?

Comment: Hm, not entirely sure - but according to this it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419899/webpack-dynamic-require-with-loaders-in-require-statement

Comment: How did you fix this error?

Comment: Continued here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052180/how-to-configure-create-react-app-in-monorepo-to-use-root-babel-config-js

Answer (score 1):

Your question helped me solve a similar issue, and I believe that this solution should work for you as well.

Instead of inlining the loader configuration for Webpack (i.e. `!babel-loader!mdx-loader!./mdx-file.mdx`), you can pre-configure this in your `webpack.config.js`, which will allow you to explicitly define the babel presets:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.mdx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader', 
                        options: {presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"]}
                    }, 
                    '@mdx-js/loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

If you have a `.babelrc` file and you don't want to duplicate your configuration, you can import it (but you will need to rename it to `.babelrc.json` for node to be able to parse it):

```
const babelrc = require('path/to/.babelrc.json');

// ....

{
    loader: 'babel-loader', 
    options: babelrc
}
```

The reason for this issue appears to be trying to parse files that are external to the project. This does not occur for internal files.