# How to configure Create React App in monorepo to use root babel.config.js?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader

Let's say I have a monorepo structure like so:

```
monorepo/
    - babel.config.js
    - create-react-app/
        - .babelrc
        - craco.config.js
    - packages/
        - first-package
            - my-mdx-file.mdx
        - second-package
```

#### How do I configure my Create React App so that it's `babel-loader` uses the root `babel.config.js`?

I need this because I'm trying to import `.mdx` files inside the CRA from one of the packages outside the CRA. [Apparently](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos), this makes the CRA's `babel-loader` fail to load it's local `.babelrc` config - and consequently miss out on the `babel-preset-react-app` preset (giving it JSX support). The import therefore results in an "unexpected token" error when babel tries to transpile the MDX file.

...I think

As you can see I'm already using [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) (to make CRA work with Less), and I've tried something like this:

```js
// craco.config.js

const CracoBabelLoader = require('craco-babel-loader')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoBabelLoader,
            options: {
                rootMode: "upward"
            }
        }
    ],
};
```

But it still doesn't load the `babel.config.js` on root ‍♂️ (I know it's not being loaded because I've placed a `console.log` statement inside `babel.config.js` like the documentation suggests - and it's not being called)